# Visual Studio 2017: ambiguous symbol size_t in linux projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 when creating Linux project and inserting `using namespace std;` in source code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    size_t i = 1;
    string s = to_string(i);
    cout << i << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

VS underlines `size_t` and says that it is an ambiguous symbol.[image: VS pic 1]

If I press F12 (`Go to definition`) it offers me two definition places:

From `stddef.h`

(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Linux\include\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu\5\include\stddef.h`):

```
// ...
namespace std
{
  typedef __SIZE_TYPE__     size_t;
// ...
```

And `c++config.h`

(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Linux\include\usr\include\x86_64-linux-gnu\c++\5\bits\c++config.h`):

```
// ...
#if !(defined (__GNUG__) && defined (size_t))
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
// ...
```

It happens only with Linux projects in VS, not with Windows projects.

Is there any known solution (except for "do not use `using namespace std;` :) )?

**Upd**: Reported this problem to Microsoft: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67405/ambiguous-symbol-size-t-in-linux-projects-when-usi.html

**Upd2**: Microsoft says that they fixed it, and solution will be in next update: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67405/ambiguous-symbol-size-t-in-linux-projects-when-usi.html

Comment: Did you try to compile the code? IntelliSense highlights every second line in my project, and it actually compiles fine.

Comment: @Rakete1111 It compiles fine. But this Intellisense curly underline bothers me.

Comment: @Rakete1111 And please DO NOT delete "visual-studio-2017" tag, this question is specific only to this version.

Comment: Intellisense is notoriously buggy with C++ code.

Comment: @vladon Well, I guess you're right. Sorry, I acted too quickly :)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ok, but I asked about known solution, for example, workaround in settings, patching headers, etc.

Comment: So what you're saying is, you only get ugly squiggles when you write `using namespace std`? That would make this the best new feature of VS 2017.

Comment: @EdHeal - The question you linked wasn't remotely a duplicate. None of the answers there provide any help here.

Comment: @CodyGray :-) But I need to maintain legacy code. VS 2017 is great, but this thing makes me crazy.

Comment: There's always the "turn off intellisense" solution.

Comment: @DeiDei Turning off Intellisense is bad solution :)

Comment: Well by the power of sense and profit, removing using namespace std; will bring you two things (no squiggles and fixing all the other problems with the statement) and turning off intellisense will bring you one thing (no squiggles). From all the economics I learned in CS university, I'd say the first is more profitable ;)

Comment: @DeiDei Yeah, thank you :-) May be I will do this. But it is definitely a bug, and I think not in Intellisense, but in C++ Linux headers in VS.

Comment: @vladon If it actually compiles fine, how can it be a bug in the headers? If Intellisense works differently from the real compiler, surely it must be an Intellisense bug?

Comment: @hvd Because it compiles with other headers (system one) on target Linux system

Comment: *a bug in Linux headers causes squiggly red lines in itellisense* Do you realise **what** Linus would answer to that?

Comment: @n.m. Read again carefully: bug in headers used for Linux projects in VS. Anyway, do you know what Linus would say about C++ itself?

Comment: Ah you mean Microsift headers for Linux projects? Yeah that could be their bug. C++ in the kernel? Yes I know what he said, I have read that. C++ elsewhere? Well he admitted he was using KDE (and, horrors, gcc itself!) so I guess no, I don't know.

Comment: @n.m. I am not Linus' apostle or prophet, so please stop about him.

Comment: Yes `defined (size_t))` certainly looks fishy, `size_t` is not supposed to be a macro.

Comment: @vladon Ah wait, that was not clear to me, sorry for misunderstanding. You're saying the error is shown with the Microsoft headers, but those Microsoft headers are *only* used for Intellisense, the actual build doesn't use them, is that right? Anyway, the specific thing those headers do (two separate identical typedefs in different namespaces) does generally work (try it: `typedef int Foo; namespace Bar { typedef int Foo; } using namespace Bar; Foo main() { return Foo{0}; }`), so I'm still not convinced it's a bug in the headers.

Comment: @n.m. I thought it is correct to use `defined(not_macro_symbol)` in preprocessor.

Comment: @hvd So how this works for Windows projects (with `using namespace std;`) ?

Comment: @vladon The headers that are used for Windows projects may happen to avoid / work around the issue, for instance by using `using` to make the same typedef available in multiple namespaces.

Comment: Hmm you are right. It's a gcc header anyway, not Microsoft's.

Comment: IntelliSense still uses the [EDG](https://www.edg.com/) compiler frontend. At the time Microsoft switched to using it, it was quite a bit ahead of Microsoft's compiler frontend with respect to standards compliance. Those times are gone, and we are now left with a situation, where IntelliSense and the actual compiler use different rule sets (and probably different environments as well). Different observable behavior is a logical consequence. Until Microsoft decide to use the same code for IntelliSense and compiling code, there's little hope for the situation to change.

Comment: I'm getting this "error" without `using namespace std;` from conflicting definitions in `vcruntime.h` and `CodeAnalysis\sourceannotations.h`

Answer (score 6):

It looks like there is a difference between Microsoft's and other compilers related to typedef in and out of a namespace.

This source file

```
namespace foo { typedef int moo; }
typedef int moo;
using namespace foo;
extern moo a;
```

compiles in g++ and clang++ (no warnings with -Weverything). MSVC rejects it because of an ambiguous symbol.

This is exactly the situation with `size_t` in gcc headers. It is  typedefed both in and out of `namespace std`. This doesn't seem to cause any problems with 
g++.

Why does this compile in g++ and not in msvc? I guess this is because of different interpretation of 7.1.3/3

> In a given non-class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.

Admittedly the interpretation by g++ is rather loose. The first `moo` is not declared within `namespace ::` so the rule seemingly doesn't apply. I cannot find anything else that would permit such a thing.

To solve the problem, I would patch the header where `size_t` is defined in the global namespace, and bring the declaration inside `namespace std` (conditionally, if `__cplusplus` is defined). But I have not tested it (no VC2017 here) and cannot guarantee it will work.

I also have no idea why your code is accepted by the actual compiler and only rejected by IntelliSense. I have tested this construction with actual compilers. (**update** to the last sentence: I have had the code tested with, and rejected by, MSVC. I have conducted the tests before realising that "the actual compiler" above is in fact gcc and not MSVC).

Comment: It is accepted actually by gcc (because linux projects from vc 2017 are compiled remotely on linux target system)

Comment: Oh I see. This makes sense.

Comment: 7.1.3/3 doesn't look like it applies here. In your second `typedef int moo;`, `foo::moo` is not in scope.

Comment: @hvd that's basically what I'm saying too.

Comment: [namespace.udir]p6 looks meant to address this: "If name lookup finds a declaration for a name in two different namespaces, and the declarations do not declare the same entity and do not declare functions, the use of the name is ill-formed." Here, both declare the same entity. But, it conflicts with [basic.lookup]p1: "Name lookup shall find an unambiguous declaration for the name (see 10.2). Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name; [...]" This requires a unique *declaration* rather than a unique *entity*.

Comment: @hvd if this isn't an open issue in the standard, it should be.

Comment: @hvd "Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name" this doesn't look rigt, most entities can be redeclared any number if times.

Comment: @n.m. Indeed. And it's not like later declarations have no effect and are discarded: `extern int a[], b[4]; int a[4], b[]; int main() { return sizeof a - sizeof b; }` only works if *both* `a` and `b` have the array bound found. For one it is in the original declaration, for the other it is in the definition.

Comment: @CodyGray Please read again. **MSVC rejects this code**. The real compiler that accepts it is apparently gcc. Of course it is different from IntelliSense.

Comment: MS answers that they fixed it, and solution will be in next update: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67405/ambiguous-symbol-size-t-in-linux-projects-when-usi.html

Comment: Fact 1: OP's compiler accepts the code. Fact 2: MSVC in my experiments rejects the code. Fact 3: gcc accepts the code. Fact 4: IntelliSense rejects the code. Fact 5: MSVC, gcc and IntelliSense all use different compiler cores. Fact 6: OP's real compiler (as opposed to IntelliSense which is not a real compiler, just a checker) is actually gcc and not MSVC. It's the fact 6 that I wasn't aware of initially, not any of 1-5. This is reflected in comments.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of fact 6 either. I still don't see where that fact is given, but that's okay. It doesn't matter to me. Sorry to have bothered you.